# How do Probability Amplitudes work?

Tags: probability, complex-numbers

In
https://en.wikipedia.org › wiki › Probability_amplitude
, I read

> In quantum mechanics, a probability amplitude is a complex number used in describing the behaviour of systems. The modulus squared of this quantity represents a probability density.

For a system represented by a set of vectors, probability density maps vectors into real probability values.   What does probability amplitude map vectors into?  Complex numbers like `x,y*i`?